# Что такое локаль?

Tags: кодировка, php

Столкнулся недавно со необходимостью установки локали. Все сделал, но полного понимания не получил.
Что есть локаль и в чем разница между локалью и кодировкой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Локаль - набор параметров, включая набор символов, язык пользователя, страну, часовой пояс, а также другие предустановки, которые пользователь ожидает видеть в пользовательском интерфейсе. ([википедия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Локаль))

Установка локали повлияет не только на вывод символов в строках, как кодировка, но и на форматы даты, времени, названия дней-месяцев, которые возвращаюбт системный функции типа `date()` и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Локаль - это набор данных указывающий на формат даты и времени, отображение валют, используемый язык и другие данные. например en_US указывает на то что это американский английский язык. Кодировка указывается через точку и en_GB.UTF-8 - значит что клиентское ПО должно выводить текст на британском английском используя кодировку UTF-8. писал как сам понимаю, [в вики примерно то-же самое](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C)

Comment: вообще говоря проще локаль это скорее ответ на вопрос "ты с какого раёна?" а кодировка -  ответ на вопрос "как вы обычно модулируете частоту для передачи данных уважаемый гуманоид?"